# POSIX shell function: printing arguments as a TSV record

Tags: escaping, sh, posix

I'm writing a POSIX shell function that prints its arguments as a TSV record.

Each argument is escaped with the following rules:

- `\n` for newline
- `\t` for tab
- `\r` for carriage return
- `\\` for backslash

Here is the function:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

tsv_print() {
    rec=
    for str in "$@"
    do
        esc=
        i=${#str}
        until [ $i -eq 0 ]
        do
            end="${str#?}"
            chr="${str%"$end"}"

            case $chr in
            "$__TAB__") chr='\t' ;;
            "$__LF__") chr='\n' ;;
            "$__CR__") chr='\r' ;;
            \\) chr='\\' ;;
            esac

            esc="$esc$chr"
            str="${end}"
            i=$((i-1))
        done
        rec="$rec${rec:+"$__TAB__"}$esc"
    done
#   echo "$rec"
    printf '%s\n' "$rec"
}
```

With the — *painful to read in code* — characters stored beforehand as follows:

```
__TAB__=$(printf '\t')
__CR__=$(printf '\r')
__LF__="
"
```

---

I would like to know:

1. <s>Why doesn't my code escape the characters at all?</s>

   <sup>***edit:*** As @GordonDavisson pointed out, `echo` was the
   culprit!! Using `printf` seems to be the only portable way, with the cost of a possible fork.</sup>
2. Is there a better, POSIX compliant, method to do it? `awk` and `sed` don't seem appropriate for the job...
3. How would you do the un-escaping?

   <sup>***edit:*** As @KamilCuk posted in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70049950/3387716), a `printf '%b'` would suffice; the TSV record has the correct format for that.</sup>

---

###### postscript

In the end, the function wasn't needed because the input didn't contain any character to escape. That said, the input format wasn't that straight-forward to convert. It was a [STAR File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-defining_Text_Archive_and_Retrieval) with varying number of columns per line (limiting the lines to 80 characters max) and containing quoted strings...

input:

```
...
loop_ 
 _refl_0201 _refl_0012 _refl_2003 _refl_1600 _refl_1304 _refl_1305 _refl_1800
 _refl_1801 _refl_1802 _refl_1803 _refl_1804 _refl_1805 _refl_1806 _refl_1701
 _refl_1700 _refl_1202
'0 0 6' .147364 Z000020c1 .41 1 78.45 3.501 35.2221 -35.2221 0 -1.6055 -3.0963
-36.7288 -5.0964 39.3109 5.909983 '0 0 12' .294551 Z000010c1 .9 1 48.44 2.3805
39.910008 39.9101 .268379-04 1.75598 3.09745 41.6656 3.09809 47.8384 0 .939517
...
```

output (separators are tabs):

```
_refl_0201 _refl_0012 _refl_2003 _refl_1600 _refl_1304 _refl_1305 _refl_1800 _refl_1801 _refl_1802 _refl_1803 _refl_1804 _refl_1805 _refl_1806 _refl_1701 _refl_1700 _refl_1202
'0 0 8' .147364 Z000020c1 .41 1 78.45 3.501 35.2221 -35.2221 0 -1.6055 -3.0963 -36.7288 -5.0964 39.3109 5.909983
'0 0 14' .294551 Z000010c1 .9 1 48.44 2.3805 39.910008 39.9101 .268379-04 1.75598 3.09745 41.6656 3.09809 47.8384 0.939517
...
```

Comment: I think your `echo` command may be interpreting the escape sequences. Try `printf '%s\n' "$rec"` instead.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why are you writing super POSIX compatible script?

Comment: The way I understand your post is that your data has embedded escape chars that you're trying to convert to "real"  "formatting" (tab, etc) characters? If yes, then, that is the road to madness. hopefully a one off. Don't accept feeds that are poorly formatted! Else edit your Q to show exact sample input text and required output. Good luck.

Comment: `$(...)` will always strip a trailing newline. But you don't need it to set `__LF__`; you can simply type `__LF__="`, hit return, then complete the command with `"`. No such tricks are necessary for `__TAB__` or `__CR__`: `__TAB__=$(printf '\t')` alone is sufficient, and likewise for `__CR__`.

Comment: @KamilCuk The target system is an old SGI IRIX, I'm not sure about the capabilities of its bourne shell.  A retired colleague of mine asked me to run one of his _super_ programs on it (they really were at the time^^), so I'll have to copy the data to an external SCSI disk (along with my script), go to the computer, run a first program with the data, convert its output to TSV, and then run the target program. My colleague told me that I'll have to convert a pseudo-CSV (no escaping, but containing tabs) to a valid TSV. Himself was doing it manually at the time...

Comment: I think the un-escaping should be a separate question. (Although, the answer will be similar, just with some different corner cases.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `sed` but there are a few tricks required to make it work.

You need to escape "\" first so backslashes from "\t", "\n" and "\r" won't get escaped.

`sed` works per line but you can just order it to add "\n" at the end of each line and remove the newline characters with a separate command.

`sed` treats the last line of the string the same regardless if it ends with "\n" or not but adding '.' at the end its input and deleting 3 last characters of the output does the trick.

This solution is a lot faster than a shell loop. (Basically, everything is faster than shell.)

```sh
tsv_print() {
    is_first_arg='yes'
    while [ $# -ne 0 ]
    do
        test "$is_first_arg" = 'yes' && is_first_arg='no' || printf '\t'
        printf '%s.' "$1" \
        | sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g' \
            -e 's/\t/\\t/g' \
            -e 's/$/\\n/' \
            -e 's/\r/\\r/g' \
        | tr -d '\n' \
        | head -c -3
        shift
    done
}
```

---

Btw, there are easier ways to define those constants.

```sh
# StackOverflow replaces the characters but it works in a file.
__TAB__='   ' # insert <tab> here
__LF__='
' # insert \n here
__CR__='
' #insert \r here
```

...or

```sh
# This one works fine when copied from here.
__TAB__="$(printf '\t')"
__LF__='
'
__CR__="$(printf '\r')"
```

Comment: No `IFS` tricks are necessary for your last example. Neither tabs nor carriage returns will be stripped from the output of `printf` by the command substitution.

Comment: (In fact, you are *globally* setting the value of `IFS` in both cases; assignments themselves don't take recommend assignments, and `printf` doesn't look for the value of `IFS` in its environment anyway.)

Comment: @chepner It seems to work fine without `IFS` on my system. I don't know why I thought it would strip "\r", although, I'm confused about the tab character. Isn't the default value of `IFS` " \t\n"?

Comment: No word-splitting is applied to the right-hand side of an assignment. It's the command substitution itself that strips trailing newlines, independent of the current value of `IFS`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better, POSIX compliant, method to do it?

I do not think so, your method is fine, and will be incredibly slow.

If "better" is speed, you can always write a POSIX-compatible C program. (But really, you can just compile GNU sed then and `sed -z` it).

I would go with `awk -v FS='' -v RS='' '{ gsub(/\\/, "\\\\"); gsub("\r", "\\r"); gsub(/\t/, "\\t"); gsub(/\n/, "\\n")} 1'`, even `busybox awk` handles that, and write the whole thing with `awk`.

> How would you do the un-escaping?

`printf "%b"`

---

```
__LF__="
"
__TAB__=$(printf '\t')
__CR__=$(printf '\r')
```

Comment: You don't need `printf` at all for newline. Just embed a newline in a quoted string.

Comment: I may write a C program if there's a compiler available on the machine but It might not be needed if the data to convert isn't too big

Comment: Well, you can cross-compile it locally and then copy it. TBH if you go that way, cross-compile busybox, and then you'll have _all_ the utilities, then write it all in awk.

Comment: Given the inout data, I had to write an awk program